# A power series with real coefficients which evaluates to $0$ for every positive real number

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, power-series, entire-functions

Let $\{a_n\}$ be a sequence of real numbers such that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_nx^n=0, \forall x \in(0,\infty)$.

Then is it true that $a_n=0, \forall n \ge 1$ ?

My try: Let $r>0$, then $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_nr^n$ is convergent, so $\lim |a_nr^n|=0$. So $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n z^n$ converges absolutely $\forall z \in \mathbb C \cap D(0,r)$. Since $r>0$ was arbitrary, so  the power series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n z^n$ converges absolutely everywhere in the complex plane.  Hence  $f(z)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_nz^n$ defines an entire function . Since $f(z)=0$ in a set with cluster points, so $f=0$ and thus $a_n=\dfrac {f^{(n)}(0)}{n!}=0$.

Is this solution right ?

Comment: Your answer is correct and it is the best answer. You may just add the fact that $(a_nr^{n})$ is bounded and $|a_n z^{n}|=|a_n r^{n}|(\frac {|z|} r)^{n}$ which makes $\sum a_nz^{n}$ convergent for $|z| <r$.

Answer (score 0):

Since $x>0$, we may divide by $x$ to achieve
\begin{equation}\tag{1}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_{n+1}x^n=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_nx^{n-1}=0.\end{equation}
Since power series are continuous, we then have
$$0=\lim_{x\rightarrow0^+}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_{n+1}x^n=a_1.$$
Then $(1)$ takes the form
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_{n+2}x^{n+1}=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_{n+1}x^n=0.$$
Can you see where this is going?

Comment: I am skeptical as to when you take $x \to 0$, whether you can distribute it over the infinite sum ... remember as given, $0$ is a boundary point ... in the meantime, I have written out a solution in the question-body ... I guess with similar arguments I have written down, without going to the complex plane, you could also say the power series converges absolutely for all real $x$ , hence it defines a continuous function on $\mathbb R$ and then the same argument as yours would go through ...

Comment: Distribution over the infinite sum is precisely what it means for the power series to be continuous. $0$ being a boundary point of your domain is not an issue as a power series always converge in a ball around their center, so convergence in $(0,\infty)$ means that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_nx^n$ converges on all of $\mathbb{R}$.