# A (probably basic) power series result.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, power-series

Suppose that
$$ h(x) := \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}a_k x^k = 0, \qquad \forall x \in (0, \infty). $$
Does it follow that $a_k = 0$ for every nonnegative integer $k$?

This is certainly true if $h(x) = 0$ for every $x$ in some neighborhood of $0$; but I'm having trouble convincing myself (one way or the other) in the case where $x$ is positive...

Since I can't, say, evaluate $h^{(n)}(0)$, the $n$th derivative at 0 (as the usual argument goes), I can't think of way to go about handling this.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3226258/a-power-series-with-real-coefficients-which-evaluates-to-0-for-every-positive

Comment: If  a power series converges for  $x=a $ then it converges for $|x|<|a|$ . So the series conveges for all real values of $x$. You can use right hand dervaitives at $0$ to show that $a_n=0$ for all $n$.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy I am trying to figure out why what you've said is true (since I certainly believe you); i.e., "If a power series converges for $x=a$ then it converges for $|x| < |a|$." Perhaps I didn't define my power series properly; so I'll try again: Let $x_0 \in (0, \infty)$ be fixed arbitrarily, and define $$h(x) := \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}a_k(x-x_0)^k. $$ Suppose we can find a neighborhood $U$ of $x_0$ such that $U \subset (0, \infty)$ and $h(x) = 0$ for all $x \in U$. If this is all we have to work with, how can we conclude that the series converges for ALL real values of $x$?